# How to check and validate the header of token?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use token in my search function. When I use token to search, it will only check the header of token to identify the request should go through all. If wrong then cancel the request and return back.

Request JSON

```
{ 
"header": { 
"Token": "558fedce-a84e-4a9a-8698-5cd27d5af3ed"
},
"body": { 
"WarehouseCode": "W001", 
"CompanyCode": "C001"
}
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        @Html.TextArea("track") <input type="submit" value="Track"/>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Model.cs

```
   public class GetInvBalReq
    {
        public class GetData
        {
            public Header header { get; set; }
            public Body body { get; set; }
        }

        public class Header
        {
            public string Token { get; set; }
        }

        public class Body
        {
            public string WarehouseCode { get; set; }
            public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

HomeController.cs

> This is the controller for search function

```
   [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string track)
        {

            UploadToBCSSoftSCM b = new UploadToBCSSoftSCM();
                string response = b.GetInvBal(track);
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response);

            return View(data);
        }
```

Comment: I am sorry but unable to understand your question. What is the issue that you are facing? are you not getting object into data after deserialization?

Comment: @sam. No, I want to use my token check the (request token) is same or not.

Comment: after deserialization data.header.Token will have token from request. so, you can compare your token with data.header.Token using string functions - Correct? By the way, I think, your data would be null as per models you have posted here, you are not deserializing to GetInvBalReq.GetData. If its null please try changing it to `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetInvBalReq.GetData>(response);`

Comment: @sam But the request Token and response Token is not the same. So if I use the response Token means that I need use hardcore for the request Token to send the web API.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TokenAuthorize: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //gettting token from headers
        IEnumerable<string> values;
        if (!actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Token", out values) || values.Count() > 1)
        {
         //if no token header found in rquest
        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
        else
        {
        //here is logic to validate your token
        //if token is not proper than you can set response as unauthorized as above
        }
    }
}
```

And then add attribute on above method like:

```
[TokenAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Index(string track)
    {

        UploadToBCSSoftSCM b = new UploadToBCSSoftSCM();
            string response = b.GetInvBal(track);
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response);

        return View(data);
    }
```